# Difference in performance executing process on layer from project or file

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, performance, vector-layer

Is there any difference between loading layer into processing algorithm from file or from current project? I have a custom processing algorithm which crashes QGIS (depending on the machine - occasionally or every time) when the layer is taken from project TOC and works normally every time if layer is loaded from file.
I checked the type of object and it is the same in both cases:

```py
@alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, name="INPUT", label="my_layer")

def my_algo(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """

    does stuff to my_layer

    """

    my_layer = instance.parameterAsLayer(parameters, "INPUT", context)

    feedback.setProgressText(repr(my_layer))  # <QgsVectorLayer: 'my_layer' (ogr)> in both cases
```

I don't know what else should I check. Are there any differences between those two methods of loading layers?

Comment: Does loading into the TOC cause a transformation to the project CRS? That's the only thing that quickly comes to mind.

Comment: I printed out CRS description and it stays the same in both cases.